# How can I stop 404 UI rendering over protected routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here are my problems...

1. My 404 renders after login to protected routes and no longer renders and I cannot access any protected routes. I've tried these three options:

   ```
   <Route component={NotFound} />
   <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
   <Route exact path="*" component={NotFound} />
   ```

... with the same result.

2. Below, you'll see  which contains side nav, nav, and main components. In main I import routes which is all I'd want to change in UI relative to routes. So, I have a main container that returns routes below.

If I place the {NotFound} component under the Layout /> it solves the #1 problem but, it inherits the UI (i.e. side nav, nav, main) from the above

What am I doing wrong such that I can't display the 404 in its simplistic UI and how can I only render it, no matter if from a protected route or not, with its UI and not the inherited UI from

Many thanks in advance! I appreciate the help.

"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"

```
function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return currentUser ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        );
      }}
    ></Route>
  );
}





function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/forgot" component={Forgot} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
          <Layout />
        </Switch>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}




const Routing = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
      ... (many more routes to be rendered in main section of UI)
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can create **ProtectedRoute** function.

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...restOfProps }) {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated");
  console.log("this", isAuthenticated);

  return (
    <Route
      {...restOfProps}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  );
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

And then you can use this function in your main App where you will declare your routes with component. Here you can add routes based on your need as well as not found component.

```
import ProtectedRoute from "./component/ProtectedRoute";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <ProtectedRoute path="/protected" component={ProtectedComponent} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I do this, the 404 renders with the protected route UI because it inherits the UI because its directly under the protected paths.

Comment: Why it's inheriting UI? You are using completely separate component for NotFound correct?

Comment: Yes, completely different. It inherits side nav, nav and renders in main.